# If we orthogonalize a vector $b$ to $u$, is $b$ then still an eigenvector?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality

Let $\mathbb K$ be an algebraically closed field. Consider $A\in\mathbb K^{n\times n}$. We know we can find $U\in\mathbb K^{n\times n}$, such that $Ue_1=\begin{bmatrix}u_1&\cdots&u_n\end{bmatrix}^T$, and also
$$
U^{-1}AU=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda&*_{12}&\cdots&*_{1n}\\
0&b_{22}&\cdots&b_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots\\
0&b_{n2}&\cdots&b_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
We also know that we can find for matrix $B$ (with entries $b_{ij}$ for $i,j\in\{2,\dots,n\}$) an eigenvector $b=\begin{bmatrix}b_2&\cdots&b_n\end{bmatrix}^T$. However, how do we know that we can turn $b'=\begin{bmatrix}*_1&b_2&\cdots&b_n\end{bmatrix}^T$ into a vector $b''=\begin{bmatrix}*_1'&b_2'&\cdots&b_n'\end{bmatrix}^T$ that is orthogonal to $u$, such that $b'''=\begin{bmatrix}b_2'&\cdots&b_n'\end{bmatrix}^T$ is still an eigenvector for $B$?

Comment: @levap Stars mean that they can be any element of $\mathbb K$.

Comment: It seems you already figured it out, but I will say for the record that the question is completely incomprehensible to me as written.  You're finding a matrix $U^{-1}AU$ such that $U^{-1}AU$ is equal to something.  What's special about that matrix on the right?  Was the goal to get the first column to be a certain way?  Is there something special about the $b_{ij}$ submatrix?  It seems like we're missing information here.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh, you're entirely right! I mixed up a couple of things. The vector $u$ has to be the first column of $U$, while the first column of $U^{-1}AU$ has to be $\lambda e_1$. I will adjust it in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I got helped by a friend, so I will post the solution he provided:

We can scale $b$ by $c\in\mathbb K$ such that $\langle \begin{bmatrix}u_2&\cdots&u_n\end{bmatrix}^T,cb\rangle=-u_1\cdot*_2$. Then we have that $b\perp u$.